# How can I remove items from div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC5 Project, there I am dynamically creating `<a></a>` attribute with remove button.

jQuery,

```js
 $("#divbindProjectlist").append('<a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList" ><span class="project-name">' + json.ProjectName + '</span><i class="pull-right close-p">x</i><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '" /></a>');
```

```html
<div id="divbindProjectlist" class="left-top-p">
    <a class="list-group-item active left-menu-head">Projects List</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList"><span class="project-name">Test1</span><i class="pull-right close-p">x</i><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="0.48063279870308406"></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList"><span class="project-name">test2</span><i class="pull-right close-p">x</i><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="0.15416046484845514"></a>
</div>
```

Here, How can I remove the each `<a></a>` attribute with respect to click on remove button ?

Please help me...

Comment: I think you meant "<a></a> tag" not attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("i.close-p").click(function () {               
            $(this).parent("a").remove();
        });
    });
```

This way the problem can be solved

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this

```
 $("#divbindProjectlist").find('a.projectList').click(function(){ this.remove();  });
```

This will attach an click event handler for  tags when they are clicked, they will be removed from the dom. Be carefull not to register multiple event listeners though (as i think you will append dynamically more than 1 time)

For not attaching multiple listeners you can do it like this

```
 var addingTag = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList" ><span class="project-name">' + json.ProjectName + '</span><i class="pull-right close-p">x</i><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '" /></a>');
 $("#divbindProjectlist").append(addingTag);
 addingTag.click(function(){ this.remove();  });
```

The above code will create an a tag and append it to your div and it will attach an event for added tag only via its reference.

Comment: Yes I am appending to more than items to this div 'divbindProjectlist' .

Comment: but I have already defined the click event like 'jQuery(document).on("click", ".projectList", function (e) {' for binding some html controls near by this div 'divbindProjectlist', then How can I apply this remove too ?

Comment: I edited my code for your needs. In JS events need to be attached "after" Elements have been created. Events attached before that will not effect newly created elements.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I remove the <a></a> when click on <i class="pull-right close-p">x</i> this button ? this is actually I need

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#divbindProjectlist").on("click", "a", function () {
            $(this).remove();   
        })
```

*Solves this problem*

Comment: how can I remove the <a></a> when click on <i class="pull-right close-p">x</i> this button ? this is actually I need.